# Normalizing Bands in All Images in Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, normalize

I am trying to normalize the values in each band across images in the imageCollection I have filtered.

I tried running this [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f0be24781c3697961546af3276ef5c96)

```
var normalized_collection = l1c_collection
  .filterDate(start_scene1, end_scene1)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
  .map(function(my_image){
    var normalized_image = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
       my_image.bandNames().map(function(name){
         name = ee.String(name);
         var band = my_image.select(name);
         return band.expression(
           '(x * slope) + intercept', {
             'x': band,
             'slope': 0.0342,
             'intercept': 0.6494});
       })).toBands().rename(my_image.bandNames());
       return normalized_image;
});
```

However, the process returned an Error: User memory limit exceeded.

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real need to first map across images, then across bands. Doing so can result in a large computational load on one node at Google Earth Engine's server-side.

It is better to use inbuilt functions which are innately parallelized on the server-side. In your case, you can use `.multiply()` and `.add()` since the slopes and intercepts are constant across images and bands.

This will look like the following:

```
var slope = 0.0342;
var intercept = 0.6494;
var normalized_collection = l1c_collection
  .filterDate(start_scene1, end_scene1)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
  .map(function(image){
    return image.multiply(slope).add(intercept).copyProperties(image)
  })
```

The above code does not run into memory errors.

[Link to complete code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/25cd14dd1a1651ebe7ca28c9f023a0c2)